# Convert Byte[]{LSB-0,MSB-0,LSB-1,MSB-1...LSB-N,MSB-N} to Int[](int-0,int-1,int-N)

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I'm looking to convert a byte array of LSB,MSB to an array of `int`

Currently, I'm using a for loop and converting each set of values individually,

```
void ConvertToInt(int OutArray[], byte InArray[], int InSize)
{
  for(int i=0; InSize/2>=i; i++)
  {
    int value = InArray[2*i] + (InArray[2*i+1] << 8);
    OutArray[i]=value;
  }
}
```

However, given that:

1. `OutArray[]` is created in the parent function for this specific purpose.
2. I don't need `InArray[]` after this operation

Is there a more efficient way to directly convert my byte array to an Int array?

Comment: Efficient as in memory use or in speed?

Comment: Can you give some sample input and its expected output?

Comment: I was looking for something in terms of speed, but I'm working with an [ATmega2560](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) So my memory is also limited.

Answer (score 0):

Operate on the array as *bytes*, then assemble and place into integers:

```
void ConvertToInt(int OutArray[], byte InArray[], int InSize)
{
  int * p_output = &OutArray[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < inSize; ++i)
  {
    byte lsb = InArray[i++];
    byte msb = InArray[i];
    int value = (msb << 8) | lsb;
    *p_output++ = value;
  }
}
```

You may need to convert to larger integers, depending on the warning level:

```
for (size_t i = 0U; i < InSize; i += 2U)
{
  const byte lsb = InArray[i + 0U];
  const byte msb = InArray[i + 1U];
  const int lsb_as_int(static_cast<int>(lsb));
  const int msb_as_int(static_cast<int>(msb));
  *p_output++ = (msb_as_int * 256) + lsb_as_int;
}
```

In the above code, the promotion of `byte` to `int` is explicit.  The variables are temporary and the compiler should simplify this (so don't worry about the temporary variables).  Also, the temporary variables allow you to see the intermediate values when using a debugger.

Print out the assembly language generated by the compiler, in both debug and release (optimized) versions, before optimizing or panicking. A good compiler should optimize the loop contents to a few instructions.

Comment: Given my Experience, I decided to go with your first answer as I believe it fits my requirements the best. After testing, I'd like to point out that the value line should be `int value = (lsb << 8)|msb`

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is little endian, then this can be done in O(1) time and additional-memory complexity.

```
int16_t *ToInt(byte inArray[])
{
  return reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(inArray);
}
```

If you either want it in a new array, or your machine is big endian, you must walk over all elements. In that case the best you can get is O(n) time complexity.

The only way to get around that, is to wrap the original array in an accessor class that will convert between byte pairs to int. Such a wrapper will speed the time for the first several accesses, but if at some point all the array has to be read, then the lazy evaluation will cost more than converting the array from the beginning.

On the positive sude, the wrapper costs only O(1) additional memory. Also, if you want to save the array as bytes, you don't have to convert.

```
class as_int {
public:
   class proxy
   {
      public:
          proxy & operator=(int16_t value)
          {
             pair_[0] = value& 255;
             pair_[1] = ((unsigned)value >> 8) & 255;
             return *this;
          }
         operator int16_t() ......
      private:
         proxy(byte*pair): pair_(pair) {}
         friend class as_int;
   };
   as_int(byte *arr, unsigned num_bytes) 
    : arr_(arr), size_(num_bytes/2)
   {}

   int16_t operator[] const (unsigned i)
   {
      assert(i < size);
      byte *pair = arr_ + (i*2);
      return pair[0] + (pair[1]<<8);
   }
   proxy operator[] (unsigned i)
   {
      assert(i < size);
      return proxy(arr_ + (i*2));
   }
  ....
```

And the use is quite trivial:

```
as_int arr(InByteArray, InSize);
std::cout << arr[3] << '\n';
arr[5] = 30000;
arr[3] = arr[6] = 500;
```